# Improving space complexity while reading from a file

Tags: c++, readfile, space-complexity

I have an arbitrarily long line of integers (or floating point values) separated by commas in a file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,...  (can go upto >100 MB)
```

Now, I have to read these values and store them in an array.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
 float* read_line(int dimension)
   {
     float *values = new float[dimension*dimension]; // a line will have dimension^2 values
     std::string line;
     char *token = NULL, *buffer = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
     int count = 0;

     getline(file, line);
     buffer = new char[line.length() + 1];
     strcpy(buffer, line.c_str());
     for( token = strtok(buffer, ","); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, ","), count++ )
       {
         values[count] = strtod(token, &tmp);
       }
     delete buffer;
     return values;
   }
```

I don't like this implementation because:

- Using `ifstream` the entire file is being loaded into the memory, and
  then being cloned into a `float []`
- There is unnecessary duplication ( conversion from `std::string` to `const char*`)

What are ways to optimize memory utilization?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a file reading with plain C? E.g. `fscanf ... "%f," ... &values[i]`

Comment: I could. Will it be preferred over @jahhaj's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
float val;
while (file >> val)
{
  values[count++] = val;
  char comma;
  file >> comma; // skip comma
}
```

Comment: There is a problem in reading once it reaches the end of a line. Any idea about how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) and `istreambuf_iterator`:

```
std::vector<float> test; //Optionally call reserve to avoid frequent memory reallocation
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>, std::istreambuf_iterator<char> > tokens(std::istreambuf_iterator<char> (in), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), boost::char_separator<char>(","));
//Replace this lambda by your favourite conversion function.
std::transform(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), std::back_inserter(test), [](std::basic_string<char> s) { return atof(s.c_str()); } );
```

edit: `test` is what I use for `values`, except it's a `std::vector` instead of arrays, which is usually the better choice.

Imho, this code has some advantages. The iterators have built-in eof handling, you can expand delimiters very easily. it's quite error-friendly (especially when you would use an atof replacement that uses exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try something based on osgx's suggestion of using scanf:

```
freopen("testcases.in", "r", stdin);
while( count < total_values)
       {
         scanf("%f,",&values[count]);
         count++;
       }
```